# Is it possible to create new badges?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges

Each SE community seems to have specific badges and those do probably help a lot the community. They rewards people for various feats regarding their implication in the site (voting, helping out) or with their questions and answers.

I was wondering who decides to create new badges (or how to suggest new ones maybe)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible, but difficult, to propose new badges, and I think that they can only be proposed network-wide rather than site-specific.

The process is described at [What makes a good badge? When and why should I suggest a new badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288251/215590)